# Shell and .bashrc different when creating users using Ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I created a new user called `superuser` using Ansible. I noticed that this user's `shell` and `.bashrc` was different to the user created manually on the system.

The first hint, the CLI output of `superuser` created with Ansible compared to root:

```
superuser prompt: $
root prompt: root@root:/etc#
```

In `/etc/passwd`, the shell for `superuser` was `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

In the end, I had to use the following Ansible command to create the super user to have the appropriate shell:

```
- name: Create super user
user:
  name: "{{ super_username }}"
  state: present
  groups: www-data
  shell: /bin/bash
  append: yes
  password: "{{ super_password | password_hash('sha512', super_salt)  }}"
```

The `.bashrc` files between `root` and `superuser` are still different.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.5 and Python 3.5.2. I'm running my script on Win10, Ubuntu WLS and Ansible 2.7.5.

In the documentation, the user module seems to indicate that the default shell should match:

> On other operating systems, the default shell is determined by the
>   underlying tool being used. See Notes for details.

Other notes:

> On all other platforms, this module uses useradd to create, usermod to
>   modify, and userdel to remove accounts.

Shouldn't `root` and `superuser` match in terms of `.bashrc` and `shell` considering the documentation?

**Edit #1**

I created a test user locally, compared its `.bashrc` and `shell` to root's `.bashrc` and `shell`. They both matched.

Comment: `.bashrc` and the shell selection are completely orthogonal concerns. For the former, you're going to want to figure out which `skel` directory was used -- if `/etc/default/useradd` doesn't specify a new one, and neither did the ansible module, then the default is *typically* `/etc/skel`, so you'd get a `.bashrc` copied from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

Comment: The other thing is that `PS1`'s `\$` renders differently based on whether the uid is 0. If you didn't give your `superuser` account a UID of 0, it's not going to behave as if it were root, even with the *exact same* `PS1`.

Comment: BTW, what do you get with `SHELL=/bin/sh useradd ...` run interactively? If it honors the value it inherited... well, we have that side of the question answered.

Comment: Ah, interesting. If I use `/bin/sh` and call `useradd test2 -m`, the `.bashrc` will match the one from `superuser`. Does this mean that Ansible is running with `/bin/sh` which explains all this?

Comment: Most noninteractive processes, when they use a shell at all, use `/bin/sh`; it's the default for the `system()` C library call and its clones in various other languages, including the `shell=True` argument for Python's `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: Thanks again. TIL! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question

> Shouldn't root and superuser match in terms of .bashrc and shell considering the documentation?

No. They should not. See [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#notes). In many systems Bash 1) doesn't have to be installed and 2) if installed, it's not the best practice for root to use it.

Comment: "Ansible root uses /bin/sh" I just came to the same conclusion, see my last comment.